# Manipulating rows in a text file with Python

Tags: python

I have a text file, with some words, each in a separate row. How can I create a new text file, which puts every 2 or 3 or X rows/words from the original file in one line?

For example, here is the input:

```
one

two

three

four

five

six

seven

eight
```

And the output what I want:

```
one two

three four

five six

seven eight
```

Comment: Can you describe what problem(s) you have? Generally speaking, you would read the content of the text file, get the rows you want to multiply (however you determine that) and then write all of that to a new file. Where exactly are you stuck? Reading the file, writing the file?

Comment: And what is the expected behaviour if there are not enough rows? For example, your file has "One Two Three" as rows, you want to combine every two rows. What happens to the "Three"?

Comment: An outline of a solution: read all words into a list, then repeatedly take _n_ words from the list and write them on the same line of the output file, until you run out of words. Use the fact that `x[pos : pos + n]` returns a sub-list of list `x` starting at position `pos`, no more than `n` elements long.

Answer (score 1):

I have wrote this to start you off. It reads the first file 'input.txt', then writes a specified amount of lines to the new file 'new.txt'.

```
lines_to_write = 5 #amount of lines to write from old file to new

with open('input.txt') as f:
    data = f.readlines()

with open('new.txt', 'w') as f:
    for x in range(lines_to_write):
        f.write(data[x])
```

This shows how to manipulate files, and should be a good basis for you to start.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wish to write a variable number of lines to one line.  So, I wrote up a list comprehension that will combine the a variable number of lines.

```
with open("in.txt","r") as fi, open("out.txt","w") as fo:
    li = fi.readlines()
    inBetween = 2
    fo.write("\n".join(" ".join(line.strip() for line in li[i:i+inBetween]) for i in range(0,len(li),inBetween)))
```

Answer (score 0):

every second line:

```
for x in xrange(len(v.splitlines())):
    if x%2 == 0:
        print " ".join(v.splitlines()[x:x+2])
```

every third line:

```
for x in xrange(len(v.splitlines())):
    if x%3 == 0:
        print " ".join(v.splitlines()[x:x+3]
```

shorter:

```
[ " ".join(v.splitlines()[x:x+2]) for x in xrange(len(v.splitlines())) if x%2 == 0 ]
[ " ".join(v.splitlines()[x:x+3]) for x in xrange(len(v.splitlines())) if x%3 == 0 ]
```

and so on...